# jaxl can't connect to Prosody

Tags: php, xmpp

I can authenticate fine with other clients including SleekXMPP and Strophe.

Using Prosody 0.8.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 and latest master HEAD of jaxl
(2518a44b9dfeb9ec947922f078cf4f8663497712).

The code:

```
require 'JAXL/jaxl.php';
$cli = new JAXL(array(
  'jid' => 'yang@localhost',
  'pass' => 'asdf',
  'bosh_url' => 'http://localhost/chat/candy/example/http-bind/'
));
$cli->add_cb('on_auth_success', function() {
  print 'yay';
});
$cli->start();
```

from client:

```
<body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" content="text/xml; charset=utf-8" to="localhost" route="xmpp:localhost:5222" secure="true" xml:lang="en" xmpp:version="1.0" xmlns:xmpp="urn:xmpp:xbosh" hold="1" wait="30" rid="3937" ver="1.10" from="yang@localhost"></body>
```

from server:

```
<body authid='72604504-a5be-4ab6-aba0-9686cca478f3' xmpp:version='1.0'
xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams'
xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh' inactivity='60' wait='30' polling='5'
secure='true' hold='1' from='localhost' ver='1.6'
sid='72604504-a5be-4ab6-aba0-9686cca478f3' requests='2'
xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'>
```

from client:

```
<body sid="72604504-a5be-4ab6-aba0-9686cca478f3" rid="3938" xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind"><auth xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl" mechanism="SCRAM-SHA-1">biwsbj15YW5nQGxvY2FsaG9zdCxyPVpRWUp0b1JwUXMwTlFkYlJ3VnlNT1FvQXN5bnhLWlN1OUpocjdVeTdkbFE9</auth></body>
```

from server:

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'
sid='72604504-a5be-4ab6-aba0-9686cca478f3' xmlns:stream =
'http://etherx.jabber.org/streams'>
```

from client:

```
<body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" sid="72604504-a5be-4ab6-aba0-9686cca478f3" rid="3939"></body>
```

From Prosody logs:

```
Oct 25 01:18:53 socket        debug   server.lua: accepted new client
connection from 127.0.0.1:41313 to 5280
Oct 25 01:18:53 mod_bosh        debug   BOSH body open (sid: %s)
Oct 25 01:18:53 bosh9096614e-a319-4234-b281-d5806b7bc558        debug
 BOSH session created for request from 127.0.0.1
Oct 25 01:18:53 mod_bosh        info    New BOSH session, assigned it
sid '9096614e-a319-4234-b281-d5806b7bc558'
Oct 25 01:18:53 httpserver      debug   Sending response to c890f0
Oct 25 01:18:53 httpserver      debug   Destroying request c890f0
Oct 25 01:18:53 httpserver      debug   Request has destroy callback
Oct 25 01:18:53 socket  debug   server.lua: closed client handler and
removed socket from list
Oct 25 01:18:53 mod_bosh        debug   Session
9096614e-a319-4234-b281-d5806b7bc558 has 0 out of 1 requests open
Oct 25 01:18:53 mod_bosh        debug   and there are 0 things in the
send_buffer
Oct 25 01:18:53 socket  debug   server.lua: accepted new client
connection from 127.0.0.1:41314 to 5280
Oct 25 01:18:53 mod_bosh        debug   BOSH body open (sid:
9096614e-a319-4234-b281-d5806b7bc558)
Oct 25 01:18:53 mod_bosh        debug   BOSH stanza received: <auth
mechanism='SCRAM-SHA-1' xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>

Oct 25 01:18:53 bosh9096614e-a319-4234-b281-d5806b7bc558        debug
 Received[c2s_unauthed]: <auth mechanism='SCRAM-SHA-1'
xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>
Oct 25 01:18:53 auth_internal_plain     debug   NODEprep failed on
username: yang@localhost
Oct 25 01:18:53 localhost:saslauth      debug   sasl reply: <failure
xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><not-authorized/></failure>
Oct 25 01:18:53 mod_bosh        debug   We have an open request, so
sending on that
Oct 25 01:18:53 httpserver      debug   Sending response to ccd1d0
Oct 25 01:18:53 httpserver      debug   Destroying request ccd1d0
Oct 25 01:18:53 httpserver      debug   Request has destroy callback
Oct 25 01:18:53 bosh9096614e-a319-4234-b281-d5806b7bc558        debug
 BOSH session marked as inactive at 1351153133
Oct 25 01:18:53 socket  debug   server.lua: closed client handler and
removed socket from list
Oct 25 01:18:53 mod_bosh        debug   Destroying the request now...
Oct 25 01:18:53 httpserver      debug   Destroying request ccd1d0
Oct 25 01:18:53 mod_bosh        debug   Session
9096614e-a319-4234-b281-d5806b7bc558 has 0 out of 1 requests open
Oct 25 01:18:53 mod_bosh        debug   and there are 0 things in the
send_buffer
Oct 25 01:18:53 socket  debug   server.lua: accepted new client
connection from 127.0.0.1:41315 to 5280
Oct 25 01:18:53 mod_bosh        debug   BOSH body open (sid:
9096614e-a319-4234-b281-d5806b7bc558)
Oct 25 01:18:53 mod_bosh        debug   Session
9096614e-a319-4234-b281-d5806b7bc558 has 1 out of 1 requests open
Oct 25 01:18:53 mod_bosh        debug   and there are 0 things in the
send_buffer
Oct 25 01:18:53 mod_bosh        debug   Have nothing to say, so
leaving request unanswered for now
Oct 25 01:18:53 httpserver      debug   Request d8b230 left open,
on_destroy is function(mod_bosh.lua:81)
Oct 25 01:18:53 bosh67a53eee-1bdb-41f6-98cb-2413808fad65        debug
 BOSH client inactive too long, destroying session at 1351153133
Oct 25 01:18:53 bosh67a53eee-1bdb-41f6-98cb-2413808fad65        info
 Destroying session for (unknown) ((unknown)@localhost)
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As log tells, Prosody is failing with authentication. Kindly try to use one of `PLAIN`, `DIGEST-MD5`, `ANONYMOUS` authentication mechanisms and it should just work fine. `SCRAM-SHA-1` and `CRAM-MD5` both are currently broken in JAXL v3.x. Let me know if it still doesn't works.