# prosody mod_bosh :Session has 1 out of 1 requests open, and there are 0 things in the send_buffer

Tags: nginx, lua, xmpp, jitsi

I am trying [jitsi-meet](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet). The environment is debian 7 + nginx + prosody (including jitsi-videobridge component).

After I start nginx , prosody and jitsi-videobridge, the prosody debug log is :

```
----------
Sep 10 10:43:17 mod_bosh    debug   BOSH body open (sid: 259ea820-4153-453e-91e2-9444b4b80fa0)
Sep 10 10:43:17 mod_bosh    debug   Session 259ea820-4153-453e-91e2-9444b4b80fa0 has 1 out of 1 requests open
Sep 10 10:43:17 mod_bosh    debug   and there are 0 things in the send_buffer:
Sep 10 10:43:17 mod_bosh    debug   Have nothing to say, so leaving request unanswered for now
Sep 10 10:43:17 socket  debug   server.lua: accepted new client connection from 192.168.0.1:40239 to 65290
Sep 10 10:43:17 mod_bosh    debug   Handling new request table: 0x28353f0: 
----------
Sep 10 10:43:17 mod_bosh    debug   BOSH body open (sid: 0236d44d-5999-48a1-8dd5-5dfe467315ea)
Sep 10 10:43:17 mod_bosh    debug   Session 0236d44d-5999-48a1-8dd5-5dfe467315ea has 1 out of 1 requests open
Sep 10 10:43:17 mod_bosh    debug   and there are 0 things in the send_buffer:
Sep 10 10:43:17 mod_bosh    debug   Have nothing to say, so leaving request unanswered for now
Sep 10 10:44:14 mod_bosh    debug   table: 0x29702d0 was soon to timeout (at 1410317057, now 1410317057), sending empty response
Sep 10 10:44:14 mod_bosh    debug   We have an open request, so sending on that
Sep 10 10:44:14 mod_bosh    debug   Request destroyed: table: 0x29702d0
Sep 10 10:44:14 bosh259ea820-4153-453e-91e2-9444b4b80fa0    debug   BOSH session marked as inactive (for 120s)
Sep 10 10:44:14 socket  debug   server.lua: closed client handler and removed socket from list
Sep 10 10:44:14 mod_bosh    debug   table: 0x29d6f40 was soon to timeout (at 1410317057, now 1410317057), sending empty response
Sep 10 10:44:14 mod_bosh    debug   We have an open request, so sending on that
Sep 10 10:44:14 mod_bosh    debug   Request destroyed: table: 0x29d6f40
Sep 10 10:44:14 bosh0236d44d-5999-48a1-8dd5-5dfe467315ea    debug   BOSH session marked as inactive (for 120s)
Sep 10 10:44:14 socket  debug   server.lua: closed client handler and removed socket from list
Sep 10 10:44:15 socket  debug   server.lua: accepted new client connection from 192.168.0.1:40240 to 65290
Sep 10 10:44:15 socket  debug   server.lua: accepted new client connection from 192.168.0.1:40241 to 65290
Sep 10 10:44:15 mod_bosh    debug   Handling new request table: 0x282c540: 
----------
Sep 10 10:44:15 mod_bosh    debug   BOSH body open (sid: 0236d44d-5999-48a1-8dd5-5dfe467315ea)
Sep 10 10:44:15 mod_bosh    debug   Session 0236d44d-5999-48a1-8dd5-5dfe467315ea has 1 out of 1 requests open
Sep 10 10:44:15 mod_bosh    debug   and there are 0 things in the send_buffer:
Sep 10 10:44:15 mod_bosh    debug   Have nothing to say, so leaving request unanswered for now
Sep 10 10:44:15 mod_bosh    debug   Handling new request table: 0x292cb90:
```

I tried different solutions :

1. [consider_bosh_secure = true;](https://github.com/maranda/metronome/issues/162), and using https
2. [The authentication is already set to "anonymous"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064858/jaxl-cant-connect-to-prosody)
3. [set timeout to 120s](http://lists.jitsi.org/pipermail/dev/2014-May/020786.html)

but none of them works. I have no idea what are the possible reasons for `there are 0 things in the send_buffer`. I guess it might be wrong port configuration in my setting.

Any ideas to help solve the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: After I upgrade jitsi-videobridge to the latest version, the message `there are 0 things in the send_buffer` gone, so it might be component problem, while not problem of prosody configuration.